# How to perform DIV better and deal with the css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-float

First, it is a loop in React and assumed as a mobile version.

Within each loop of `DIV`, it will have a photo(150*150px) on the left-hand side.
On the photo's right-hand side, it will have 3 `div` and each of the `div` will have a `p` (name, car and salary). At the bottom, it will have a line and its length will be the same as the parent `div`.

One special is that the `p`of car will have many words, when the width of the phone is not enough, it will go to the next line. If it is still not enough, it will become Tesla, Honda, BMW,...

it is the  [Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev0id.jpg)

I really try many methods(float, position,...), but I still cant deal with it,

Here is the HTML part (using React)

```
<div className='loop'>
   <img className='image' src={value.image}></img>
       <div>
           <p className='title'>{value.name}</p>
       </div>
       <div class>
           <p className='car'>Tesla, Honda, BMW, Porsch,Mitsubishi, Mazda, Toyota, Jaguar, KIA </p>
       </div>
       <div>
           <p>{value.salary}</p>
       </div>
       <div className='linebreak'></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with grid :

```css
.loop {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: .5em;
  width: 400px
}
.image {
  grid-row: span 3;
}
.linebreak {
  margin-top: .5em;
  grid-column: span 2;
  border: 2px solid #4f86f7;
}
.loop p, img {
  border: 2px solid #777696;
  margin: 0;
}
.title {
  align-self: start;
}
.salary {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class='loop'>
   <img class='image' src="https://picsum.photos/100" />
   <p class='title'>name</p>
   <p class='car'>Tesla, Honda, BMW, Porsch,Mitsubishi, Mazda, Toyota, Jaguar, KIA </p>
   <p class='salary'>salary</p>
   <div class='linebreak'></div>
</div>
```